# Android, OpenCv: crop fails when crop occurs within function

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-camera

I have a class which receives frames taken with a camera. It then passes the frame to a camera calculator, which does some processing and crops according to the camera calculator's aspect ratio setting.

When I have...

```
@Override
public void receivePicture(Mat frame) {
    mCameraCalculator.processFrameForResult(frame);
    //the image is then saved   
}

//in camera calculator...
public void processFrameForResult(Mat frame){
    processFrame(frame);
    frame = frame.submat(getCenterByAspectRatio(frame)); //crop
}
```

The crop fails (the saved image is not cropped). However, when I have...

```
@Override
public void receivePicture(Mat frame) {
    mCameraCalculator.processFrameForResult(frame);
    frame = frame.submat(mCameraCalculator.getCenterByAspectRatio(frame)); //crop
    //the image is then saved   
}

//in camera calculator...
public void processFrameForResult(Mat frame){
    processFrame(frame);
}
```

It works perfectly. This does not make sense. Are these two bits of code not equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, `receivePicture` and `processFrameForResult` are in two different classes. In the top code block, you are doing the cropping in the `CameraCalculator` class. The trouble lies in the `processFrameForResult` method when you assign `Frame`. This line does not actually assign the cropped `Frame` back to the `Frame` variable, because once the method returns, the input  `Mat Frame` variable it is no longer in scope. For more details on why this is, [please see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) that goes into detail on the differences between pass by reference and pass by value.

If you would like the top code block to work, then your `processFrameForResult` method in the top code block must return the `Mat Frame` object instead of void.